# FB api name to a global variable javascript

Tags: javascript, fbconnect

So I have this facebook login javascript code and say I want to make changes to a global variable that goes inside this function, is that possible? so I want to make something like this:

```
var Name;
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '2295720594086082',
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v3.2'
      });

      // FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);

        FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          Name = response.name;
        })
    });
console.log(Name);
```

But I always get that `Name` is undefined, I know that this function is Asynchronous but I don't know how to use this....

Comment: Have you tried to place the console.log call below "Name = response.name" ? Name will only be defined when the callback is called (the response received).

Comment: @Pedroleal Yes and it works, but when I try to call it outside the function it doesn't work anymore

Comment: That's because it's an asynchronous function. Read the answer of the question that yours was marked as duplicate.